# Symfony2 DQL on Fos Userbundle entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, query-builder

I'm implementing a search on a website and for simplicity i've decided to create a class that does the hard work.

Basically my class takes the EntityManager and the Entities in which i want to search and creates the DQL and executes the query. For normal entities this works totally fine but when i pass the User entity (Extended from fos user bundle entity) i get this error :

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 139 near 'last_login LIKE': Error: Class Soundmerger\UserBundle\Entity\User has no field or association named last_login

The dql query generated seems fine and as it works for the other entities i doubt it comes form there.

Here is my Search class :

```
use Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;

class Search {

private $em;

private $searchables;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em, ArrayCollection $searchables){
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->searchables = $searchables;
}


public function search($query){
    $words = explode("+", $query);

    $qb = array();
    $results = array();
   foreach($this->searchables as $qNumber => $searchable){
        $qb[$qNumber] = "SELECT s FROM $searchable s ";

        $columns = $this->em->getClassMetadata($searchable)->getColumnNames();

        foreach($words as $i => $word){
            foreach($columns as $k => $column){
                $string = "s.$column LIKE '%$word%'";
                if($i == 0 && $k == 0){
                    $qb[$qNumber] .= "WHERE $string";
                } else {
                    $qb[$qNumber] .= "OR $string";
                }
            }
        }

        $res[] = $this->em->createQuery($qb[$qNumber])->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_SIMPLEOBJECT);
    }


    return $this->formatSearch($res);
}


private function formatSearch($results){
    $formatedResult = array();

    foreach($results as $k => $result){
        if(!empty($result)){
            $formatedResult[$k]["type"] = get_class($result[0]);
            $formatedResult[$k]["data"] = $result[0];
        }
    }


    return $formatedResult;
}
}
```

And my Controller for the search :

```
/**
 * @Route("/search/{query}")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction($query)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $searchables = new ArrayCollection(
        array(
            "SoundmergerUserBundle:Professional",
            "SoundmergerFaqBundle:Faq",
           "SoundmergerUserBundle:User",

        ));
    $search = new Search($em, $searchables);


    return array('search' =>  $search->search($query));
}
```

And finally my user entity :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @AttributeOverrides({
 *     @AttributeOverride(name="emailCanonical",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(
 *             name     =   "emailCanonical",
 *             type     =   "string",
 *             length   =   255,
 *             nullable =   true
 *           )
 *         ),
 *      @AttributeOverride(name="email",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(
 *             name     =   "email",
 *             type     =   "string",
 *             length   =   255,
 *             nullable =   true
 *           )
 *         ),
 *      @AttributeOverride(name="username",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(
 *             name     =   "username",
 *             type     =   "string",
 *             length   =   255,
 *             unique   =   false
 *           )
 *         ),
 *      @AttributeOverride(name="usernameCanonical",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(
 *             name     =   "usernameCanonical",
 *             type     =   "string",
 *             length   =   255,
 *             unique   =  false
 *         )
 *     ),
 * })
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

const STRUCTURE_SOLO = "solo";
const STRUCTURE_GROUP = "group";


/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 * @var string
 */
protected $nomProfile = null;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = null;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 * @var string
 */
protected $type = null;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @var string
 */
protected $structure = self::STRUCTURE_SOLO;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 * @var string
 */
protected $tel = null;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 * @var string
 */
protected $site = null;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 * @var bool
 */
protected $firstLogin = true;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Soundmerger\MainBundle\Entity\Address", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $address;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Soundmerger\MainBundle\Entity\Style", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $styles;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Soundmerger\UserBundle\Entity\Member", mappedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
protected $members;


/** @ORM\Column(name="discogs_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
protected $discogs_id;

/** @ORM\Column(name="discogs_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
protected $discogs_access_token;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->members = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->styles = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get id
 * @return string
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Get NomProfile
 * @return string
 */
public function getNomProfile()
{
    return $this->nomProfile;
}

/**
 * Get type
 * @return string
 */
public function getType()
{
    return $this->type;
}

/**
 * Get structure
 * @return string
 */
public function getStructure()
{
    return $this->structure;
}

/**
 * Get tel
 * @return string
 */
public function getTel()
{
    return $this->tel;
}

/**
 * Get site
 * @return string
 */
public function getSite()
{
    return $this->site;
}

/**
 * Get description
 * @return string
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set nomProfile
 * @param string $nomProfile
 * @return \Soundmerger\UserBundle\Entity\Utilisateur
 */
public function setNomProfile($nomProfile)
{
    $this->nomProfile = $nomProfile;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set type
 * @param string $type
 * @return \Soundmerger\UserBundle\Entity\Utilisateur
 */
public function setType($type)
{
    $this->type = $type;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set structure
 * @param string $structure
 * @return \Soundmerger\UserBundle\Entity\Utilisateur
 */
public function setStructure($structure)
{
    if (!in_array($structure, array(self::STRUCTURE_SOLO, self::STRUCTURE_GROUP))) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid structure");
    }

    $this->structure = $structure;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set tel
 * @param string $tel
 * @return \Soundmerger\UserBundle\Entity\Utilisateur
 */
public function setTel($tel)
{
    $this->tel = $tel;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set site
 * @param string $site
 * @return \Soundmerger\UserBundle\Entity\Utilisateur
 */
public function setSite($site)
{
    $this->site = $site;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set description
 * @param type $description
 * @return \Soundmerger\UserBundle\Entity\Utilisateur
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set the first login
 * @param bool $firstLogin
 * @return \Soundmerger\UserBundle\Entity\Utilisateur
 */
public function setFirstLogin($firstLogin)
{
    $this->firstLogin = $firstLogin;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Is it the first login
 * @return bool returns true if its the first login, false otherwise
 */
public function isFirstLogin()
{
    return $this->firstLogin;
}

/**
 * Set address
 *
 * @param Address $address
 * @return $this
 */
public function setAddress(Address $address)
{
    $this->address = $address;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get adress
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAddress()
{
    return $this->address;
}

/**
 * @return Style
 */
public function getStyles()
{
    return $this->styles;
}

/**
 * @param Style $style
 * @return $this
 */
public function addStyle(Style $style)
{
    if (!$this->styles->contains($style)) {
        $style->setUser($this);
        $this->styles->add($style);
    }
    return $this;
}

public function setStyles(PersistentCollection $styles)
{
    foreach ($styles as $style) {
        $this->addStyle($style);
    }
}

/**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getMembers()
{
    return $this->members;
}

/**
 * @param Member $members
 */
public function addMember(Member $member)
{
    if (!$this->members->contains($member)) {
        $this->members->add($member);
    }
    return $this;
}


public function setDiscogsId($discogs_id)
{
    $this->discogs_id = $discogs_id;
    return $this;
}

public function getDiscogsId()
{
    return $this->discogs_id;
}

public function setDiscogsAccessToken($discogs_access_token)
{
    $this->discogs_access_token = $discogs_access_token;
    return $this;
}

public function getDiscogsAccessToken()
{
    return $this->discogs_access_token;
}


public function isRegisteredWithDiscogs(){
    return $this->discogs_id != null;
}
}
```

Any ideas on why this is only happening with the user entity (it must be due to the inheritance but i can't seem to find a way round it)

btw : its a university project so the idea of using an external bundle for the search is not really possible.

Thanks for any help

Dan

Comment: You say you're using FOSUserBundle but you are using `Class Soundmerger\UserBundle\Entity\User` ?  Your User class does not have a `$lastLogin` variable set...also what is the `BaseUser` you are extending and where does it come from?

Comment: The BaseUser is the fosuser bundle entity, the one you extend to add columns to the user. The lastLogin is in the BaseUser class. Anyway i've found the problem, its that the doctrine builder does not support extended/inherited entities.